# Counting and Grouping in Python: Error Message

Tags: python, grouping, counting, eoferror

***People have posted about this same problem (writing a program for this exact same case) but no where on the website did I see anyone whose code returned this error. Note: I want to know how to fix the error, not about the problem itself. I could not find another question about this error. This is not a duplicate question. ***

I have the following program to count the number of each item ordered. The items that a customer can order are: salad, hamburger, and water. For example: If order = "hamburger water hamburger" then the function returns "salad:0 hamburger:2 water:1"

```
from collections import Counter

(meal) = raw_input("order= ")

def item_order(meal, items=('salad', 'hamburger', 'water')):
    counter = Counter(meal.split())
    return ' '.join(['{}: {}'.format(item, counter.get(item, 0)) for item in items])

print(item_order(meal))
```

When I run the program through PowerShell, it works perfectly and prints exactly what I need, yet when I tried to submit it in my online course it returned:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "submission.py", line 3, in <module>
    (meal) = raw_input("order= ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line"
```

I am very new at this and I don't understand why this error came up or what it means or how to fix it. I tried googling the error but it was very confusing. Can anyone help?

Comment: You have an additional quote in your last line.

Comment: I have a feeling this has to do with the specifics on how your online course is expecting you to take input. check if you are supposed to be doing input from a file rather than from the stdin. UNRELATED: the brackets around `(meal)` are unnecessary

Comment: Unfortunately that was just a typo on the website. When I googled the error code, someone said "if raw_input function hits an end-of-file condition (EOF) without reading any data, it will throw out the EOFError exception." I don't understand this. What's the end-of-file condition and how is it not reading any data?

Comment: Thanks so much @RNar . I will definitely check that out!

Comment: I've been on both ends of this problem.  Please re-read your assignment.  I expect that you'll find you're supposed to read input from a specified file, not from the input console.  The automated on-line validation has a different interface (doesn't feed input to the standard console channel), and returns this error.  Check the input requirements carefully, and please update the question to reflect what you find.

Comment: @Prune : These are my instructions word for word. "Write a function called item_order that takes as input a string named order. The string contains only words for the items the customer can order separated by one space. The function returns a string that counts the number of each item and consolidates them in the following order: salad:[# salad] hamburger:[# hambruger] water:[# water] " I have been pondering every possible answer I could and still everything I try comes up with the same error. I don't even know what to attempt anymore.

Comment: I recommend that you check this with the help forum for your on-line class.  Get the input requirements clarified. The class likely proscribes posting your code, but you should be able to ask a specific question.  For instance, you can probably mention that you used "raw_input" to get the order, but that appears to get rejected in automated testing.

Comment: Thanks much appreciated! @Prune

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a way to test this right now but try using double quotes. By the way it works fine in my terminal as well.

example:

```
def item_order(meal, items=("salad", "hamburger", "water")):
```

instead of:

```
def item_order(meal, items=('salad', 'hamburger', 'water')):
```